# Error al querer compilar en angular 7 con firebase: 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'App'

Tags: base-de-datos, angular, firebase, npm, angular7

Se me presento el siguiente problema al querer compilar, estoy utilizando angular en su version 7, lo siguiente se presenta al arrancar ng serve:

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts(17,22):
>   error TS2420: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface
>   'App'.
>         Property 'performance' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp' butrequired in type 'App'.

Ya me esta comiendo la cabeza.

Comment: Echa un ojo a esta pregunta relacionada, tal vez te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55933656/6139307

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ilsanchez ha sido de mucha ayuda tu consejo, el error se soluciona cambiando la dependencia de firebase del 5.11 al 5.10, con esto ya se puede seguir trabajando, dejo el comando para el cambio de dependencia.

```
npm i --save firebase@5.10.0
npm i --save firebase-admin@5.10.0
```

Saludos.